# Pandas groupby solo con año y mes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Buen día, tengo un programa en Python usando Pandas, en donde lee dos dataframes, que se obtienen de los siguientes enlaces:

Casos-positivos-diarios-en-San-Nicolas-de-los-Garza-Promedio-movil-de-7-dias:
https://datamexico.org/es/profile/geo/san-nicolas-de-los-garza#covid19-evolucion

Denuncias-segun-bien-afectado-en-San-Nicolas-de-los-GarzaClic-en-el-grafico-para-seleccionar:
https://datamexico.org/es/profile/geo/san-nicolas-de-los-garza#seguridad-publica-denuncias

Lo que quiero hacer por el momento es hacer un groupby en la tabla de "covid" con las fechas que sean iguales, sacando una suma de estos. Sin embargo, ningún método que he intentado me funciona, por lo regular me marca que es porque necesita una sintaxis para manejar "PeriodIndex". ¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia o solución para esto?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

#csv for the covid cases
covid = pd.read_csv('Casos-positivos-diarios-en-San-Nicolas-de-los-Garza-Promedio-movil-de-7-dias.csv')

#csv for complaints
comp = pd.read_csv('Denuncias-segun-bien-afectado-en-San-Nicolas-de-los-GarzaClic-en-el-grafico-para-seleccionar.csv')

#cleaning data in both dataframes

#keeping only the relevant columns
covid = covid[['Month','Daily Cases']]
comp = comp[['Month','Affected Legal Good', 'Value']]

#changing the labels from spanish to english
comp['Affected Legal Good'].replace({'Patrimonio': 'Heritage', 'Familia':'Family', 'Libertad y Seguridad Sexual':'Sexual Freedom and Safety', 'Sociedad':'Society', 'Vida e Integridad Corporal':'Life and Bodily Integrity', 'Libertad Personal':'Personal Freedom', 'Otros Bienes Jurídicos Afectados (Del Fuero Común)':'Other Affected Legal Assets (Common Jurisdiction)'}, inplace=True, regex=True)
#changing the month types to dates
covid['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(covid['Month'])
covid['Month'] = covid['Month'].dt.to_period('M')

covid
```

La línea que intenté y me causó un error `covid.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Month', axis=0, freq='M')).sum()`

El error que imprime
`axis must be a DatetimeIndex, but got an instance of 'PeriodIndex'`

Answer (score 0):

Pude encontrar una solución:

Lo único que tuve que hacer fue un groupby antes de cambiar el tipo de dato en la fecha, además de optimizar el código para el cambio a fecha.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

#csv for the covid cases
covid = pd.read_csv('Casos-positivos-diarios-en-San-Nicolas-de-los-Garza-Promedio-movil-de-7-dias.csv')


covid = covid.groupby(['Month'])['Daily Cases'].sum()
covid = covid.reset_index()
# #changing the month types to dates
covid['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(covid['Month'])
covid['Month'] = covid['Month'].dt.to_period('M')

covid
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).